# splash hace que se cierre la app

Tags: java, android

hice un splash screen y le puse una imagen de fondo, y carga bien en mi samsung s8, sin embrago en el j5 hace que se cierre, ya revisé el min sdk y debería cargar en un j5, luego quite la imagen del splah y carga bien...al parecer es el hecho de que ponga una imagen, lo mismo me pasa en cualquier layout que use una imagen de fondo. no se que pasa ojala me puedan ayudar. les dejo el xml, java y   el build gradle

gradle

```
     apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }


    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.birkonapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.codesgood:justifiedtextview:1.1.0' //Justificar texto
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.2.0'
}
```

java

```
public class splash extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent intent=new Intent(splash.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();

            }
        },3000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya lo resolví, lo que sucede es que habia ubicado las imagenes que usa la app en la carpeta equivocada, las tenia en la carpeta drawable v-24 y las puse en la carpeta drawable y corrió perfectamente. de todas formas gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Yo te recomiendo hacer el Splash lanzando primero una clase que extienda de `AppCompatActivit`, es decir que va ser un activity, pero esta no tendra un layout asociado. Esto lo hacemos mediente el `manifest` con

```
         <activity
             android:name="splash"
             android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
             <intent-filter><         
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
             </intent-filter>
         </activity>
```

**SplashTeme** dentro de `styles`

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
</style>
```

En `drawable` **background_splash.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
    android:opacity="opaque"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:drawable="@color/colorAccentInto"/>
    <item>

        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/neww"/>

    </item>

</layer-list>
```

En `splash.java`

```
public class Splash  extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Listo, el splash, simeplemente le puedes hacer creando una clase, ya que como vez no utilizamos el `setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash)` pues la vista carga metiende `android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"` que definimos nosotros mismos.

Lo interesante de esto es que no necesitas hacer la mala practica de crear un hilo  por unos segundos y lanzar el layout de la actividad como "splash", si utilizas este truco el splash desaparecerá cuando la vista de la siguiente actividad que lanzaste este construida ;)

Comment: ok. muchas gracias, se ve mas complejo, pero voy a intentar hacerlo...gracias! y una pregunta.. por que me ocurre lo mismo en cualquier layout de la app donde ponga una imagen en backgraund?